# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module routerApp ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to Angular.js and can't seem to get ui-router to load. I've gone through a couple google searches now and haven't been able to resolve this error. Right now, I have pared down my code just to ensure that ui-router is working, but I continually get the following error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            .navbar { border-radius:0; }
        </style>

        <script src =  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="public/javascripts/test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="routerApp">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="container">

            <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
            <div ui-view></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
var routerApp = angular.module("routerApp", ["ui.router"]);

routerApp.config(
  ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("views/ui-views/home.html");

      $stateProvider

        .state("home", {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "views/ui-views/home.html",
          controller: "tmp1Controller"
    });
}]);

routerApp.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

  }
]);
```

Any recommendations as to how to resolve the issue?

Comment: First,you should unify variable name. I see `app` and `routerApp`.

Comment: I should've caught that before posted. Unfortunately, that is not the issue.

Comment: try moving  `ng-app="routerApp"` from `body` to the `html` tag

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: There must be something else somewhere that breaks your code, as the above works perfectly

Comment: Also, are you sure the path to `test.js` is correct?

Comment: this is inside an otherwise empty express skeleton. Would that have any influence?

Comment: Also, based on the error you receive, `[$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available!`, it seems that you have  `app` instead of `routerApp` somewhere

Comment: Sorry, I haven't updated the error with fixing variable names. Current error:

Comment: Failed to instantiate module routerApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/nomod?p0=rou...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error: express did not like my path to my javascript file. Changing

```
<script src="public/javascripts/test.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="../../javascripts/test.js"></script>
```

seemed to do the trick.

Comment: the ui-router is still not functional, but the described error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The `app` is not available in the view. It should be `routerApp`

```
var app = angular.module("routerApp", ["ui.router"]);
```

Comment: Wow, I should've caught that before i posted. Unfortunately, however, that was not the issue.